# Get element created by Bootstrap with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get in JS an element created by Bootstrap but it always give me an `undefined` response. Since the element is like that

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm search-input" type="search" placeholder="Cerca" autocomplete="off">
```

so there's no ID's i tryed to use class so like follow:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('loaded ' + document.getElementsByClassName("form-control-sm")[0])
    
})
```

but is not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: perhaps you run the code before the element exists

Comment: Wait the DOM to be fully loaded i guess

Comment: What about using `document.getElementsByClassName('search-input')`

Comment: Maybe you are calling the code before the element exists. Try to create a button that calls the function that finds your element and click it after the search input is generated, just for testing porpouse. If that's the case you should make the code wait the DOM

Comment: I've edited the question because i didn't explained very well, sorry and thanks

Comment: You do realize you have a space in the classname you use as a parameter for `getElementsByClassName()`? That space should not be there.

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to access the element before the element exists. The window load event listener will trigger before the element exists. Can you give some context? What's the element that bootstrap autogenerates? Is it part of any component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery Solution to select the searchbar:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm search-input" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search here..." />

<script>
  $(".search-input").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fefffa");
    alert("Keyup func works!");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said the id attribute doesn't work, is there any explanation for that? Anyways, this should work...

```
<input id="searchbar" class="form-control form-control-sm search-input" type="search" placeholder="Cerca" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    document.getElementsById("searchbar");
});
```

*Used double-quotes in the parameter*

Note: the load event will make sure the page has fully loaded before getting the element...

Comment: The id doesn't work because Bootstrap didn't give it to that element so I can't give it manually

Comment: In your code you've added a space after 'form',  like this : "(getElementsByClassName("form- control-sm"), remove the space...and let me know if it works! (:

Comment: sorry, digit mistake creating the question

Comment: cool, please check the error_log file if there's one or check if there are errors in the console using the chrome inspect feature (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Comment: I'm trying ot use an onkeyup func on that and it throw me the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of undefined```

Comment: Coincidently, I am working on the same type of search bar with the onkeyup function rn! (I'm using jQuery)
Are you willing to try the solution using jQuery? I can give solutions in jQuery too...

Comment: I'll be glad of any type of solution and I'm alredyusing JQ  

Comment: Aight, I'll give a jQuery solution as the answer, hope it works for you...